# How to calculate MvxListView height after binding?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I want to resize MvxListView to make it show all elements inside ScrollView 
*(I actually want MvxListView with Header and CustomAdapter, but that just too hard to implement).*

I tried several ways, with OnMeasure

```
    protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
        // View.MeasuredSizeMask represents the largest height possible.
        var expandSpec = MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(MeasuredSizeMask, MeasureSpecMode.AtMost);

        base.OnMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

        SetMeasuredDimension(MeasuredWidth, (int)2 * MeasuredHeight);
    }
```

With OnDraw:

```
    protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        if (Count != _oldCount)
        {
            _oldCount = Count;
            _params = LayoutParameters;
            _params.Height = CalculateHeight();
            LayoutParameters = _params;
        }

        base.OnDraw(canvas);
    }
```

where CalculateHeight was:

```
    private int CalculateHeight()
    {
        var height = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < ChildCount; i++)
        {
            height += GetChildAt(i).MeasuredHeight;
            height += DividerHeight;
        }
        return height;
    }
```

And even:

```
private int CalculateHeight()
    {
        var mAdapter = Adapter;

        int listviewElementsheight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Adapter.Count; i++)
        {    
            var mView = mAdapter.GetView(i, null, this);

            mView.Measure(MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified),
                MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified));

            listviewElementsheight += mView.MeasuredHeight;
            listviewElementsheight += DividerHeight;
        }
        return listviewElementsheight;
    }
```

But I noticed that everywhere height of elements is the same. Element has this layout

```
<TextView
    android:text="Title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/List.Secondary"
    local:MvxBind="Text Title; TextColor FineInfoColor(IsHighlighted)" />
<TextView
    android:text="Content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/List.Primary"
    local:MvxBind="Text Content" />
```

and second TextView can have from one to ten lines of text.
I suppose this is the problem - it calculate height based on layout and not an actual row height. Am I right? How can i fix it?

Comment: I used a MvxListView with Header and CustomAdapter before so it is not that hard to make. You just need to follow some of the tutorials out there: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/602

Answer (score 1):

Use MvxLinearLayout instead of MvxListView.